# Smooth Movement

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, game-physics

I am attempting to recreate the old Mario game using jQuery and the d pad and I'm having trouble having him jump up and fall down a set amount while having the right/left still move smoothly. Here is my project so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/NpKgc/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).keydown(function (key) {
    switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 38:
            $(".mario").animate({
                top: "-=50px"
            });
            $(".mario").animate({
                top: "+=50px"
            });
            break;
        default:
            break;
        case 83:
            $(".mario").addClass("crouching");
            $('.mario').attr('src', 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSstp0TMfI46ImPw3Ynoq8N64Trn9ew70Dzh8NR4u4VLm40nccV');
            break;
    }
    });
});
setInterval(movePlane, 20);
var keys = {};
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});
function movePlane() {
    for (var direction in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(direction)) continue;
        if (direction == 37) { //left
            $(".mario").animate({
                left: "-=5"
            }, 0);
            if (!$('.mario').hasClass('flipped')) {
                $(".mario").toggleClass("flipped");
            }
        }
        if (direction == 39) { //right
            $(".mario").animate({
                left: "+=5"
            }, 0);
            if ($('.mario').hasClass('flipped')) {
                $(".mario").toggleClass("flipped");
            }
        }
        if (direction == 40) { //down 
            if (!$(".mario").hasClass(!"crouching")) {
                $(".mario").toggleClass("crouching");
                $('.mario').attr('src', 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSstp0TMfI46ImPw3Ynoq8N64Trn9ew70Dzh8NR4u4VLm40nccV');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to how I can do this? As seen, it moves sideways after the jumping motion completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you animate statements are colliding. And since you are already using interval, there is no need to use animate for left and right:

http://jsfiddle.net/NpKgc/3/

```
    if (direction == 37) { //left
        $(".mario").css({
            left: "-=2"
        });
        if (!$('.mario').hasClass('flipped')) {
            $(".mario").toggleClass("flipped");
        }
    }
    /*if (direction == 38) {//up
        $(".mario").animate({top: "-=5"}, 0);
    }*/
    if (direction == 39) { //right
        $(".mario").css({
            left: "+=2"
        });
        if ($('.mario').hasClass('flipped')) {
            $(".mario").toggleClass("flipped");
        }
    }
```